# Law of large numbers for a sequence of random variables with converging moment

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of random variables such that,

$$
\forall n,\,\,\mu_n := EX_n < \infty, \quad \mu_n \to \mu < \infty \textrm{ as } n\to\infty.
$$

Now for each $n$, let $X_{n,1}, \dots, X_{n,n}$ be i.i.d. copies of $X_n$. Define
$$
\bar X_n := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{n,i}.
$$

I want to prove that
$$
\bar X_n \to \mu \textrm{ as } n\to\infty,
$$
almost surely. I'm guessing it should be true, but don't know how to prove it.
I tried to utilize existing proofs of law of large numbers, but most of the proofs I could find on Google uses additional assumption like finite variances, which may not hold for my case.

Can anyone give me a hint to prove this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not true, even if all $X_n$ have the same distribution.  See Exercise 24 of [Terry Tao's notes](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/23/275a-notes-3-the-weak-and-strong-law-of-large-numbers/)

Comment: Thank you for a great reference. I've seen a hint attached to Exercise 24, and it said to prove that $\bar{X}_n$ is unbounded almost surely. But what if $\bar{X}_n$ is always bounded? In my case, $X_n$ is a bounded random variable such that $0 \leq X_n \leq A_n$, with $A_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Still not true?

Comment: E.g. try $X_n = n^2$ with probability $1/n^2$, $0$ otherwise.  Then $\mathbb E[X_n] = 1$, but $\mathbb P(\bar{X}_n = 0) \ge 1 - 1/n$.